# How to change Datetime CultureInfo to a DateTime variable

Tags: c#, datetime

I have created datatable as the data source of my gridview. However, it shows US format `mm/dd/yyyy` and I want to show GB format `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Therefore I tried to modify this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in DT.Rows)
{
    if (Convert.ToString(row["Modified"]) != "")
    {
        DateTime LLISubmitDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row["Modified"]);
        row["Modified"] = LLISubmitDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    }
}
courseList.DataSource = DT;
courseList.DataBind();
```

It obviously brings error because I append a string instead of DateTime.

So any idea for this?

Comment: DateTime itself has no format (it's just a number). Are you trying to display the date somewhere, like in a data grid? If so, then the data grid must be set to the right formatting.

Comment: Since the date is stored as a DateTime and not string, your best bet would be to handle it in the `View` or whichever way you're showing the DateTime. For windows, usercontrols, pages, etc, they all have ways to 'display' the datetimes in custom formats.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL some column is fixed in GB format, some I want to set all date to GB format as well

Comment: Is this ASP application?

Answer (score 1):

This might do the trick for you

```
string d = "";
int i = 0;
foreach (DataRow row in DT.Rows)
{
    if (Convert.ToString(row["Modified"]) != "")
    {
        d = ((DateTime)row["Modified"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        YourDataTable.Rows[i]["Modified"] = d; // I believe it should be courseList 
        i++;
    }
}
```

Because In .NET Framework, `DateTime` structure doesn't have any implicit format. It just have date and time values. You get it's string representation when you try to format it.